# My SQL Query to get Mutual/Friends Followers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the one below:

```
id | Follower_id | leader_id | status
---------------------------------------- 
1  |   2         |  1        | approved
2  |   1         |  2        | approved
3  |   3         |  2        | approved
4  |   1         |  3        | approved
```

From this table, I want to retrive the Follower_id/leader_id that are mutual.

For examples 2 , 1 are mutual in this table. To achieve this I am using the following sql

```
SELECT r.follower_id RF
     , r.leader_id   RL
     , l.follower_id LF
     , l.leader_id   LL
  FROM followers r
  JOIN followers l
    ON l.follower_id = r.leader_id 
   AND l.leader_id = r.follower_id 
 WHERE r.status = 'approved'
   AND l.status = 'approved';
```

It returns the expected output, but it is very slow.

How can I optimize this SQL?

Comment: Can you add expected result? It's a parent-child relation?

Comment: What do you mean by "takes more time" ? How much time does this query takes; also Run `EXPLAIN..` on your current query, and post it results here. Also, any optimization related requirements also need to mention the indexing details on the table (if any). Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE..` and post its result as well

Comment: Hint: make indexes on `status` column first..

Comment: You can make the primary key a combination of `Follower_id` and `leader_id`. You don't need the `id` here, because you will then get a unique combination for each row on the follow/leader IDs.

Comment: You could concatenate both ids into one comma separated value in ascending order (CASE, CONCAT_WS), GROUP BY that combined value, and limit the result to those HAVING a COUNT > 1 … you’d have to check if that performs better with a larger data sample though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something simpler might work faster, e.g.

```sql
SELECT follower_id, leader_id 
FROM followers a  
WHERE follower_id IN (
   SELECT follower_id 
   FROM followers b 
   WHERE a.leader_id = b.leader_id 
   AND status = 'approved' 
)
AND status = 'approved';
```

Comment: The `follower_id` is probably never the same as `leader_id` in the same row, so `WHERE follower_id = leader_id` will probably return 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the whole table with the same table. That make no sense. Try the Inner Join so it will gave you the cut where the Leaders have the same followers or the followers the same leaders. Also you need to use an `as`Alias to join your tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM followers as f
INNER JOIN followers as k on f.follower_id = k.leader_id
WHERE f.follower_id like k.leader_id OR f.follower_id = k.leader_id
```

Before someone shit storm me, this is an example script which is shown you all entrys of bouth tables. In this case two times the same table.

Better for this is to make 2 Tables. Create an Accounting Table and an Follow Table and join them. should be works fine aswell and faster.

If you want more methods to join Tables take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: there are no differences between JOIN and INNER JOIN. You are using the same join method as OP. The only difference is in the WHERE clause.

Comment: yea but if he have an old/outdated Interpreter it could be the case that the join command would be used like an left or right outer join. It's better to call the full name of the function instead the short cut. That was my problem 2 years ago.

Comment: OP is returning the correct results so the mysql server is updated enough... the question is about performance

Comment: I can only imagine that the MySQL server or the Apache server have too little RAM available. That MySQL Code isn't so long and hard so it can't be take longer then 1 sec i guess. Maybe it is also due to the interface that calls the whole thing.

Comment: there are many reasons why that query can be slow: indexes for examples. Apache is not involved at all and the hardware is not since OP is pointing at just one query, do you agree?

Comment: Of course I do but I hope that you agree my points as well xD The list could be ended and I can't imagine why the MySQL Query should be the result of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query produce a duplicate records. This also create some delay for your mysql connection.

To avoid duplication is to solve your problem.

I add my works below,

```
SELECT r.follower_id RF
     , r.leader_id   RL
     , l.follower_id LF
     , l.leader_id   LL

  FROM sample r

  JOIN sample l
    ON l.follower_id = r.leader_id 
   AND l.leader_id = r.follower_id AND r.id < l.id


 WHERE r.status = 'approved'
   AND l.status = 'approved';
```

Output:

```
RF  RL  LF  LL
2   1   1   2
```

Note: Use your `table name` insteed of `sample`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes EXISTS is very efficient:

```
select 
  t.follower_id id1,
  t.leader_id id2
from followers t
where 
  status = 'approved'
  and
  t.follower_id < t.leader_id
  and 
  exists (
    select 1 from followers
    where status = 'approved' and follower_id = t.leader_id and leader_id = t.follower_id 
  )
```

This query will return each pair only once.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uU45QiyAaRjoRoSsr2LRyc/0).
Results:

```
| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 2   |
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can optimize this query with indexes:

```
SELECT r.follower_id as RF, r.leader_id as RL,
       l.follower_id as LF, l.leader_id as LL
FROM followers r JOIN
     followers l
     ON l.follower_id = r.leader_id AND
       l.leader_id = r.follower_id 
WHERE r.status = 'approved' AND l.status = 'approved';
```

The following index should help:  `followers(follower_id, leader_id, status)`.

I would prefer to write this as `exists`.  You might also try aggregation:

```
SELECT f.follower_id, f.leader_id
FROM followers f
WHERE f.status = 'approved'
GROUP BY LEAST(f.follower_id, f.leader_id),
         GREATEST(f.follower_id, f.leader_id)
HAVING MIN(f.follower_id) = MIN(f.leader_id);
```

The last condition guarantees that you have both directions in the data.